# AWStats and proftpd | AWStats never updates

Tags: update, proftpd, awstats

AWStats never updates when parsing my proftpd log file.

Here's what I get :

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/share/awstats/www/awstats.pl -config=ftpcnam:2121 -update  

Searching new records from beginning of log file...  
Jumped lines in file: 0  
Parsed lines in file: 1  
 Found 0 dropped records,  
 Found 0 comments,  
 Found 0 blank records,  
 Found 1 corrupted records,  
 Found 0 old records,  
 Found 0 new qualified records.
```

Here's what my vhost configuration look like :

```
ExtendedLog /home/cnam/ftp/logs/proftpd_log read,write awstats
TransferLog none
```

And in the main proftpd configuration file :

```
LogFormat awstats "%t   %h  %u  %m  %f  %s  %b"
```

I did put a tab char instead of space between the `%tags` in the `LogFormat` directive.

I put in the awstats configuration of the vhost :

```
LogType="F"
LogFormat="%time1 %host %logname %method %url %code %bytesd" 
LogSeparator="\t"
```

Answer (score 2):

This log format does not work with AWStats. It is considered as corrupted by AWStats, maybe because of your local language.

```
/usr/lib/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=exemple.com -showcorrupted
```

You have to change the log format of both ProFTPd and AWStat:

- ProFTPd (with tab char instead of space):

  ```
  LogFormat awstats "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t %h %u %m %f %s %b"
  ```
- AWStats:

  ```
  LogFormat="%time2 %host %logname %method %url %code %bytesd"
  ```

Doc:

- [ProFTPd LogFormat](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_LogFormat.html)
- [strftime(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)